# How to create an extra table per entity with inherited fields from an abstract class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I want to have 2 tables created per entity: one with the original properties, and the other with the same fields plus the ones inherited from an abstract class.

For example:

**Entity Class (Product):**

- Description
- Category
- Stock

**Abstract Class:**

- UpdatedBy
- UpdatedAt

The result I expect would be:

**Table Products:**

- Description
- Category
- Stock

**Table Products_Abstract:**

- Description
- Category
- Stock
- UpdatedBy
- UpdatedAt

What I'm trying to avoid is creating a class inheriting the abstract per entity because I wont be using it in the project. I only need the table creation, functional with migrations, so if I update Product in the future and add a new migration, both tables should suffer the changes.

I think that something like this is what I'm looking for:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .Map(m => m.ToTable("Products"))
        .Map<AbstractClass>(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Products_Abstract");
        });
}
```

But this code is for EF6, and I'm using EF Core without the posibility to change it.

Thanks in advance. English isn't my main language, I hope you understand.

Comment: `I want to have 2 tables created per entity`. Why ?!? This looks like an XY-Problem.

Comment: @Spotted The second one is to audit all changes made in the first one.

Comment: Why is it a problem to store `UpdatedBy` and `UpdatedAt` alongside with the rest of the properties ? Would [this strategy](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) solve your problem ?

Comment: @Spotted No. The purpose of the duplicated fields is to keep track of the values before the changes. The Product table have current values, and if a make an update, an entry is add to the other table with the previous values, and product table is updated with the new values.

Comment: Would it be possible to make your audit class an interface ? Any reason you want to implement your own system instead of using an existing ? Are you forced to save these values in the database or could it also be in log files ?

Comment: @Spotted The audit class is an interface. Actually, I'm trying to implement Audit.NET with EF Data Provider. The framework works but it doesn't implement migrations: I have to create the audit tables by myself. I could create a class per each of my entities extending both entity and audit interface. This way, EF will create a new table per each of that classes too, but also leave me with a bunch of classes a wont be using anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For creating table with two models, you could try like below:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }       

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        foreach (var property in typeof(Product).GetProperties())
        {
            builder.Entity<Products_Abstract>()
                   .Property(property.PropertyType, property.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

```
public class Abstract
{
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    foreach (var property in typeof(Product).GetProperties())
    {
        builder.Entity<Abstract>()
                .ToTable("Products_Abstract")
                .Property(property.PropertyType, property.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution implies that I have to create a Products_Abstract class, and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @JuliánPera `Products_Abstract` is only the name, check my update answer.

Comment: I tried that way: the Products_Abstract table is created, but the Products table is not.

Comment: @JuliánPera Have you configured `public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }  ` in `DbContext`? For `builder.Entity<Abstract>().ToTable("Products_Abstract")`, it is used to create `Products_Abstract` table.